# Getting 404 Not Found error while trying to use ErrorDocument

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I know this thread has been talked a lot on the web and here, and I tried almost all the methods, but still I'm having the same problem.

This is my url on my local server ( MAMP )

```
http://localhost:8888/hellothere/index.php
```

And I've tried to insert a wrong path to take me to wrong page , like below :

```
http://localhost:8888/hellothere/eiurgiuerib
```

Instead of taking me to Error Page it shows :

```
Not Found

The requested URL /hellothere/eiurgiuerib was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

My 404 page is inside of the Error directory. And inside my .htaccess file I have included this :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /Error/404.php
```

Comment: The custom error page is not working. So what should I do ?

Comment: can you show your folder schema?

Comment: Please don't use images to show text data. It's saying that /Error/404.php can't be found -- Check spelling, capitalization, and directory and file permissions. You should be able to invoke 404.php from the browser address -- is it found?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `ErrorDocument` directive, when supplied a local URL path, expects the path to be fully qualified from the `DocumentRoot`. In your case, this means that the actual path to the `ErrorDocument` is

```
ErrorDocument 404 /hellothere/error/404page.html
```

Comment: One more think , If in my index.php page I just add this line of code " header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");  " It won't take me to 404 page, why is that ?

Comment: @user1725155 you should read this article [custom 404 not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914120/php-header-404-not-working)

Comment: Many thanks, I was repeatedly trying to beat this into apache from the server root and not the document root.

Answer (score 1):

When we apply local url, ErrorDocument directive expect the full path from DocumentRoot.
There fore,

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /yourfoldernames/errors/404.html
```