# Show 404 error page from PHP file, without redirecting

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

I have a file `secret.php` which is included in `index.php` and I want to show a 404 error page when someone tries to access `secret.php` directly. But

```
header("Location: this_site_certainly_does_not_exist");
```

in `secure.php` is not a solution, because I want the URL the user typed (e.g. `example.com/secret.php`) to be visible in the browser's URL bar when the error page is shown, instead of redirecting.

Comment: Check this Answer for a possible solution [https://stackoverflow.com/a/61230899/7327747](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61230899/7327747)

Answer (score 14):

You can do it with headers.

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

then you can add your 404 page using for example `readfile` method.

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
echo "<h1>404 Not Found</h1>";
echo "The page that you have requested could not be found.";
exit();
```

Comment: If you have a different 404 page template, just `file_get_contents` or `include` it.

Comment: From where include it ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to send a html 404 status code to the client. You can achieve that with:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

Comment: It only send 404 status code to the client and not show default 404 error page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would want to keep that in browser, best practice is to redirect the user to a 404 page.

I'd suggest to do it with an apache (.htaccess) or nginx redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your application architecture, but Codeignter does this by including a common file that is used in all files (in their case index.php)

The index.php file includes a define

```
define('BASEPATH', $system_folder.'/');
```

And then in files that should only be used by being included in other files

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

See how you can adopt that scheme for your own situation.

Answer (score -1):

for permanent solution you can use .htaccess for redirecting when secret.php is called

```
  # Mod for redirecting specific URL requests to a custom error page
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/secret.php [NC]
  RewriteRule . /your-error-page.php [L]
  # End of custom mod
```