# PHP GET passing unknown parameters doesn't display error page

Tags: php

I'm developing a website using GET super global to catch category name and display related posts mysite.com/cat?name=sports, but when I pass wrong or a parameters that doesn't exist mysite.com/cat?name=fsdf it shows me a category page with the parameter name but without any related posts, I want it to display 404 error page, I tried to check if the category name exists and if not it will be redirected to error page but I don't want that - I don't want to change what URL shows in the address bar when the error page is shown.

> > the page that I want to display error has variable name like this mysite.com/cat?name=xx  if xx is not a recognized category I want to display 404 error in the same url no redirect

Comment: Please give us some code...

Comment: Please clarify what you want and what you have. It sounds like you have a page already that checks if the category exists and if not it redirects. Also adding code would be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show 404 error page for existed php file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300789/show-404-error-page-for-existed-php-file)

Comment: @MarkAmery that's a different question, thanks

Comment: @AhmedSallam It looks the same to me. What's the difference?

Comment: Can u share the code and explain what u need if yur conditions already working

Comment: @MarkAmery the difference is I'm passing a parameter to catch the page name so the name is variable and not static so may be infinite pages all of them wrong except the ones I've created in my database

Answer (score 0):

You can use the appropriate header 404 in case a category does not exist. Try this one:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

Make sure your server knows how to handle 404 responses.